# point process whose domain is Z+

Tags: stochastic-processes

Hi all,
I am very new to this field.
I am curious to know, what is a natural way to define point process on the
space of positive integers(Z+) ?
I saw Z+ valued point process, but I am not sure how one can define it On Z+.
Is it well defined there ? Because in the definition of point process
it seems there is no restriction on the domain itself. I might be wrong.
Let me know.
thanks,
--Subhajit

Answer (score 1):

A point process on Z+ is just a random subset of Z+.

In general, a point process on a set $S$ is a random point pattern in $S$, which you can think of as a countable subset of $S$ without limit points. On Z+, all subsets are countable and don't have limit points (assuming you're working with the usual discrete topology, and take its Borel $\sigma$-algebra), so any subset will do.

Comment: In the litterature, "point process" allows for multiple points, meaning in some point, say 0, it is possible to have 0, 1, 2, 3, ... (thus a random point process is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{Z}_+}$). It is a necessary assumption if for instance you define a Poisson point process on Z+. 

Comment: Elena and Remark, thanks for your prompt reply.